# Entity Framework Context failing with ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a simple Entity Framework Code First context for persisting events as they arrive from the bus. The context is :

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext (DbConnection connection)
        : base(connection, false)
    {

        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
        Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
    }

    public DbSet<MyEvent> MyEvents { get; set; }

}
```

where MyEvent is

```
public class MyEvent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }

    public string MessageId { get; set; }

    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I try to access the context.MyEvents collection I get a ReflectionTypeLoadException

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

with LoaderException

> "Method 'ToCombinedRows' in type 'XXXX' from assembly 'YYYY' does not have an implementation."

Now this is *really* strange as the type XXXX is completely unrelated to the object being persisted and has no reason to have a method of this name.

All the objects are defined in the same assembly, and I am running from an integration test project, with references CopyLocal set to true. Does anyone know how to get my context to talk to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem.

I was running the integration tests using ReSharper, which loads the assembly into a temporary location, and Entity Framework could not work out the types in that location (it was fine when I ran from a Console app). For reasons that I do not know, when I split the context objects into their own assemblies, Entity Framework ran fine. So, not a problem with the references in the project, just a problem loading these references into the test harness.